# Cannot send a collection of integers to a Web Core Api Post method, it is set to null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to send a collection of integers to a post method on a web core api.

The method is;

```
[HttpPost("open")]
public IActionResult OpenInspections([FromBody]IEnumerable<int> inspectionIds)
{
    return NoContent();
//...
```

This is just for testing, I put a break point on the return statement and the `inspectionIds` payload is `null`.

In Postman I have

[image]

EDIT: I have just removed the square brackets from the signature. I was trying both `IEnumerable<int>` and `int[]` but neither worked

Comment: I guess JSON should be `{ "inspectionIds": [11111111, 11111112] }`? You're sending array of strings, but controller expecting collection of integers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is null because what is posted and what is expected by the action do not match, so it does not bind the model when posted. Example data being sent has a `string` array `["11111111", "11111112"]` and not `int` array `[11111111, 11111112]`,

also `IEnumerable<int>[]` represents a collection of collections, like

```
{ "inspectionIds": [[11111111, 11111112], [11111111, 11111112]]}
```

To get the desired behavior either update action to expect the desired data type

```
[HttpPost("open")]
public IActionResult OpenInspections([FromBody]int[] inspectionIds) {
    //...
}
```

Making sure that the posted body also matches what is expected

```
[11111111, 11111112]
```

### **OR**

consider using a concrete model as the posted data in the provided question is a JSON **object**.

```
public class Inspection {
    public int[] inspectionIds { get; set; }
}
```

And update the action accordingly

```
[HttpPost("open")]
public IActionResult OpenInspections([FromBody]Inspection model) {
    int[] inspectionIds = model.inspectionIds;
   //...
}
```

the model would also have to match the expected data being posted.

```
{ "inspectionIds": [11111111, 11111112] }
```

Note that if the desired ids are suppose to be `int` then do not wrap them in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here: `IEnumerable<int>[]` - it's array of lists of ints?

It should be simple `int[]` (or it could be `IEnumerable<int>`).

Comment: Apologies you have spotted the error in my question. I have tried both of your alternatives with the same result.

Comment: In that case, it must work with no need extra model, but... I didn't catch it before - the name of the variable in action signature is not important, just your json object must fit c# Type, so if you want to get `int[] xxx` then just send an array of ints directly `[11111111, 11111112]` without wrapping it in an extra json object like here `{ "xxx": [11111111, 11111112] }`.